# pMaria db not accepting parentheses in FROM Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, parentheses

Mariadb v10.1.8-MariaDB appears to be refusing parentheses in multiple table from clauses.  the same sql works in  5.5.44-MariaDB and MySQL 5.5.39
Am i doing something stupid ?

```
SELECT 
    acdd_studentprogrammes.STU_ID, 
    acdd_studentprogrammes.Stage, 
    acdd_stages.StageType, 
    acdd_fte_values.FT_PT, 
    acdd_fte_values.FTE_Value
FROM 
    (acdd_studentprogrammes 
        INNER JOIN acdd_stages ON acdd_studentprogrammes.Stage = acdd_stages.Stage) 
    LEFT JOIN acdd_fte_values ON acdd_studentprogrammes.FT_PT = acdd_fte_values.FT_PT;
```

Comment: Why not just remove the parentheses?

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle for this failure? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: derived tables mus have a name ...... FROM (SELECT * FROM acdd_studentprogrammes 
        INNER JOIN acdd_stages ON acdd_studentprogrammes.Stage = acdd_stages.Stage)  AS TMP

Comment: thanks fro some responses: 
@sagi - this is a simpler example, in the real queries there are many joins, the parentheses specify which tables are joined to which.

Comment: @BerndBuffen - that makes sense to me, is this a new restriction on maria db ?  older mariadb and mysql seem to allow me to omit naming the derived table. thanks, j

Comment: ups, my mistake: SELECT * FROM (answer LEFT JOIN DATA ON answer.id = data.id); works for me. which error you get ?

Comment: i have tested with 10.1.10-MariaDB-log - it works

Comment: I'm getting "Unexpected token. (near acdd_studentprogrammes)"

its definitely the bracket (there are no hidden weird characters etc)

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Hi sagi, i havent tried your answer, but it looks like a sub-query approach would work.. however, what i'm trying to establish is why mariadb v10 rejects a query that works in mariadb v5 and Mysql v4 and 5.
i have pages of this to migrate and don't really want to re-code it all for a single server

Comment: @BerndBuffen: so my version of your working Query would be:
SELECT *
FROM (acdd_studentprogrammes LEFT JOIN acdd_stages ON acdd_studentprogrammes.Stage = acdd_stages.Stage);
This still gives me the same error, i'm starting to wonder if my PMA is broken

Comment: can you post me the creates of the tables to test it on my system

Comment: hmm - i'm going to say its something wrong with the syntax checker in my version of phpMyAdmin… I've just done numerous tests PMA doesn't like the brackets in your example.. take them away and its fine. If i preceed the query with "CREAT VIEW xxx" (which is what i'm really doing), it accepts the brackets and executes the query correctly ! - similarly, with other VIEWs that i've migrated.. they execute correctly, but if i paste their SQL into the window, it throws a tantrum.
thanks for helping me solve this

Comment: meh - updated PhpMyAdmin and the errors persist.. however some of them must be warnings because you can ignore them and still get the desired results.. 
eg:  DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `acdd_v_tutors_ug1`;
throws an warning.. then says executed ok :-/
silly PMA !